# How can I change Local Security Policy through comand line

Tags: command-line, local-security-policy

I have a windows 10 machine and I need to change the Security settings to not defined for Local Security Policy->Local Policies->Security Options->
DCOM:Machine Launch Restrictions in SDDL syntax
and
DCOM:Machine Access Restrictions in SDDL syntax from a command line.

Would anybody know how to do this?

Comment: how do you expect regular windows readers to see your Q. Best if you add a tag for Windows-10. But I'll be surprized if this is possible, as it seems like you're trying to thwart security. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DCOM  " /v MachineLaunchRestriction /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DCOM  " /v MachineAccessRestriction /f
```

Deleting the keys worked